# unable to ssh into ec2 server created by terraform

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm using packer to create a custom AMI with docker installed.
I then try to add docker swarm.
Unfortunatly it fails because terraform is not able to ssh into any of the machines.

**terraform apply**

This is printed 100 times in the log before everything stops:

```
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec):   Host: 35.176.154.111
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec):   Private key: true
aws_instance.swarm-manager (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
```

I opened AWS EC2 console in the browser and found the public IP of the bastion server. Tried to connect but failed:

I am able to ssh into the servers myself. Terraform is not abel to access the EC2 instances.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/terraform-eu-west-2.pem  ubuntu@ec2-35-176-213-56.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**Key pairs**

For the eu-west-2 region I have created a key I've named terraform. This is saved as ~/.ssh/terraform-eu-west-2.pem

**All my files on Github**

I've saved all the whole shebang to a [github repo](https://github.com/stabenfeldt/terraform-docker-swarm-aws/tree/patch). Please have a look.

At the very end of the output from `terraform apply` I get this. I think it's because I'm not able to ssh in, but I'm not sure.

```
Error applying plan:

4 error(s) occurred:

* aws_instance.swarm-node[2]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Script exited with non-zero exit status: 125
* aws_instance.swarm-node[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Script exited with non-zero exit status: 125
* aws_subnet.c: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_subnet.c: Error creating subnet: InvalidParameterValue: Value (eu-west-2c) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid. Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones: eu-we
st-2a, eu-west-2b.
        status code: 400, request id: 5459c120-f60b-4beb-9acb-323c4bc3c06d
* aws_instance.swarm-node[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Script exited with non-zero exit status: 125
```

The error says: `Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones: eu-west-2a, eu-west-2b`. But if I change region from *eu-west-2* to *eu-west-2a* I get an error saying `* provider.aws: Not a valid region: eu-west-2a`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing [regions/availability zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html). Region `eu-west-2` has only 2 valid zones: `eu-west-2a, eu-west-2b`. But your Terraform code is trying to use also invalid zone `eu-west-2c`. Remove that `c` zone part from your Terraform code or use region, where also `c` zone is available (for example `eu-west-1`).